# Outlook 2007 send from this account by default

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2007

Is there a way to setup Outlook not to have a default account to send from? i.e. I want to be prompted each time I send an email (using Outlook 2007) for the email account to use.

Comment: very useful question.  +1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This won't prompt you for which account, but if you click on the *Account* button under *Send* then you can select which account to send the message from.

See [Choose  which e-mail account to use to send a message](http://web.archive.org/web/20100318035356/http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/HP101024371033.aspx?) for more information.

Comment: That's how I currently do it but thanks for the suggestion anyway - it's a good one +1.

Answer (score -1):

1. Tools > Account Settings... > Email tab
2. Highlight the account you want to be the default send account.
3. Click [Set as Default] button.

Comment: OP clearly asked for there NOT to be a default account. You have answered the opposite of what was asked.

Comment: Wow, you're right.  I found this question by looking for a way to change the default account, and I totally missed the "not" in the question.